# Nativescript UI-Builder and Databinding

Tags: javascript, data-binding, nativescript

I try to build a custom component consisting of multiple TextFields. This component should use twoWay databinding via Observable internally. But I am simply not able to get it working.

## main.js

```
exports.loaded = function(args){
    var page = args.object;
    page.bindingContext = model;

    var outerContainer = page.getViewById('outerContainer');

    model.vma = new Observable({
        label: "NiceLabel"
    });
    var vma = durationRow.init({
        model: model.vma
    });

    outerContainer.addChild(vma);
};
```

## widget / durationrow.js

```
exports.init = function(options){
    model = _.isUndefined( options )
        ? model
        : options.model;

    _.defaults(model, {
        label:      "no data given",
        start:      "",
        end:        "",
        duration:   "30"
    });

    var durationRow = builder.load({
        path: 'widgets/durationRow',
        name: 'durationRow',
    });

    durationRow.getViewById("startText").bind({ 
        sourceProperty: "start", 
        targetProperty: "text", 
        twoWay: true }, 
    model);

    return durationRow;
}
```

The data originally in the `start`, `end`, `duration` fields get inserted into the `text` properties of my XML-layouted view. But changes on the model don't get propagated into the UI after the initial "render".

I tried XML-based databinding via `text={{ start }}` in my XML and this JS-based data binding. Both only works in "initial render" no updates get promoted.

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I got some things wrong. I built the whole `init` thing because I wasn't able to get "data" to my "widget". After all it all happens based on a simple small error... I tried to use `bindContext` instead of `bindingContext` and all hell...

So the working solution:

main.js

```
var row = builder.load({
    path: 'widgets/durationRow',
    name: 'durationRow',
    attributes: {
        bindingContext: rowData
    }
});
```

And now nothing else is needed in durationRow.js. All JS-access to `rowData` is done via bindingContext and everything works like a charm :)